# How can I transform linear equations into the form $a\,x+b\,y+c=0$?

Tags: output-formatting

I have a bunch of line equations generated by the following code:

```
Clear[eq, pts]
eq = Simplify[Det[{{x, y}, -Subtract @@ #}] == Det[#]] &;
pts = 
  {{{0, 3}, {4, 0}}, {{-1, -2}, {4, -2}}, {{3, 4}, {3, -2}}, {{1, -2}, {5, 1}}};
eq /@ pts
```

The outputs are given as follows.

> ```
> {3 x + 4 y == 12, 2 + y == 0, x == 3, 3 x == 11 + 4 y}
> ```

#### Question

How can I reformat the outputs to be in the form of $a\,x+b\,y+c=0$?

Note that, although the form $a\,x + b\,y + c == 0$ is fine, I would accept the form $a\,x + b\,y + c = 0$.

Comment: `TeXForm /@ ((eq /@ pts) /. x__ == y__ :> x - y == 0)`.

Comment: @Montevideo: Very good! Thank you. Do  you want to post it as your answer? Or I delete the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SubtractSides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractSides.html):

```
SubtractSides /@ {3 x + 4 y == 12, 2 + y == 0, x == 3, 3 x == 11 + 4 y}
```

> ```
>   {-12 + 3 x + 4 y == 0, 2 + y == 0, -3 + x == 0, -11 + 3 x - 4 y == 0}
> ```

```
TraditionalForm /@ %
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can modify `eq` using a custom `ComplexityFunction` in `Simplify`:

```
Clear[eq2]
cF = LeafCount[#] + 5000 Count[#, HoldPattern@Equal[_, Except[0]], All] &;

eq2 = Simplify[Det[{{x, y}, -Subtract @@ #}] == Det[#], ComplexityFunction -> cF] &;

TraditionalForm /@ eq2 /@ pts
```

[image: > {-12 + 3 x + 4 y == 0, 2 + y == 0, -3 + x == 0, -11 + 3 x - 4 y == 0}]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[eq, pts]
eq = Defer@*Plus @@ MonomialList[FactorList[Det[{#1 - #2, #2 - {x, y}}]][[2, 1]]] == 0 &;
pts = {{{0, 3}, {4, 0}}, {{-1, -2}, {4, -2}}, {{3, 4}, {3, -2}}, {{1, -2}, {5, 1}}};
eq @@@ pts
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by:

```
TeXForm /@ ((eq /@ pts) /. x__ == y__ :> x - y == 0)
```